# No entra en la funcion cuando le doy click

Tags: javascript

```
var imagenes = ['imagenes/vis1.jpg', 'imagenes/vis2.jpg', 'imagenes/vis3.jpg']
cont = 0;

function carrousel(visitanos) { 
    visitanos.addEventListener('click', e => {
        let atras = visitanos.querySelector('.atras'),
        adelante = visitanos.querySelector('.adelante'),
        img = visitanos.querySelector('.visis'),
        tgt = e.target;
        if(tgt == atras) {
            if(cont > 0) {
                img.src = imagenes[cont -1];
                cont--;
            } else {
                img.src = imagenes[imagenes.lengt -1];
                cont = imagenes.length -1;
            }
        } else if(tgt == adelante) {

            if(cont < imagenes.lengt -1) {
                img.src = imagenes[cont +1];
                cont++;
                confirm("mensaje");
            } else {
                img.src = imagenes[0];
                cont = 0;
            }
        }
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoader", () => {
    confirm("mensaje");
    let visitanos = document.querySelector('.visitanos');
    carrousel(visitanos);
});
```

Comment: Podrías describir cuál es el problema. Qué pretendes hacer y por qué no te funciona...

Comment: no me funciona cuando le doy click, seria un carrousel de imagenes entonces cuando le quiero dar click a atras o adelante no me cambia la imagen

Comment: Tienes un *typo* en el caso "adelante", `if(cont < imagenes.lengt -1) ...` debería ser `length`.

Comment: y si pero de igual forma, yo le pongo alguna alerta o algo para ver si me entra en la funcion y no salta nada

Comment: Deberias colocar el html tambien, no todo, pero si lo necesario, puede ser que enrealidad nunca estes accediendo a ese elemento y por lo tanto no le estas agregando ningun evento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El evento al que te suscribes está mal escrito. Es `DOMContentLoaded`.
[Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) tienes la documentación.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    // ...
});
```

Y, como mencionaba en el comentario, tienes un *typo* al acceder a la *property* `length`, te falta la "h".

Espero que sirva.

Comment: gracias, si me funciono